# Do all compiled codes have same speed no matter what language they were written in?

Tags: performance

Suppose I write a program in both Python and C++ and I turn these to executable. Now, will both the executable have the same speed or will it vary (I guess it shouldn't cause it should now be in machine code form) ?

Comment: Do all poems mean the same thing, even if they are written in different languages?

Comment: @RBarryYoung sorry but my question was about writing the same poem in two different languages.

Comment: Not what the title says.  But OK, "*Suppose I write a poem in Navah and Farsi, will they both have the same impact on those who read it?*"

Comment: @RBarryYoung Obviously not sir..!Now you have got the right example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Suppose I write a program in both Python and C++ and I turn these to executable. Now, will both the executable have the same speed

Of course usually not (assuming both code implement the same [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm)). And the runtime speed depends a lot of the compiler itself (e.g. `tinycc` -for C- and [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) ....) and even of its versions and compilation flags (e.g. `-Os` vs `-O2` with `g++`). BTW, Python is compiled to some bytecode, not to machine code.

Of course, some software are mostly spending CPU time elsewhere (e.g. in some relational database manager such as [PostGreSQL](https://postgresql.org/)). Then rewriting them in C++ instead of Python won't gain a lot of performance. And some software are mostly IO bound (e.g. [tar(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html) used without compression)

At last, some C++ programs could generate machine code at runtime (e.g. using [AsmJit](https://asmjit.com/)...) using [partial evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation) techniques, which may give a huge speedup.

On Linux, you could generate some C or C++ code at runtime, compile it as a temporary plugin, then [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) that temporary plugin (fetching new function pointers using [dlsym(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)... Adapt the [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c) example to your needs)

Also, C++ is a very difficult language to learn. Read some [good book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html) about it.

### Read of course the [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools).

Since an entire book is needed to answer your question !

Comment: i know python is compiled to bytecode i am talking about, executable is that bytecode too..? I don't think we need compilers/interpreters to run executables.Your answer helped a bit but am still confused.

Comment: Yes, you need to read several books on that topic. You could also do some simple benchmarks, and start a PhD on that very topic

Comment: It means the executable that i generate from python will be slower than the one i generate with cpp..?

Comment: @AjaySinghRana it will most likely be, but that is not BECAUSE of this

Comment: It also depends very much on how they write the two different programs.  Poorly written C++ will not necessarily be faster than well written Python, especially for more sophisticated things.

Comment: @Felix could you write some more about it..?

Comment: It really cant be described in short. It is a complex topic. And I'm not nearly the best person to go much into detail about this.

Comment: okay...I'll read the book then.:):):)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch surprisingly i bought the **Dragon Book** last year but couldn't even start reading it. Thanks, i guess i need to use my resources now.

Comment: I guess that having some prior programming experience helps. Notice that [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) with some [internal documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/). You are allowed to download its source code and study it. You'll need more than a full year of work.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch haven't worked much with C++ or C but just Python. Now am thinking of making a shift.Will learn about GCC too.